# The difference between "follow-up" and "next" in context

Tags: word-usage, difference

Tell me please if there is any difference between the following sentences?

> I can't go for a break as I have to prepare the classroom for the **follow-up** students.
>
> I can't go for a break as I have to prepare the classroom for the **next** students.

Comment: You need to use "next" in this particular instance.  Follow-up normally means the further work or effort that is required to get something done, where as next just means the succeeding thing or event.

Comment: Sorry Dmytro, to clarify my comment.  In the sentences above, you are using "next" as an adjective to describe the "next students".  "Follow-up" is a noun, which is why it doesn't make sense when used that way.  If you want to use next you have to change its position to use it as an adverb, for example "I can't go for a break as I have to prepare the classroom for the students that are arriving next".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your given context, "follow-up" sounds wrong.

Normally, when using "next" to refer to a succession of people it means *different* people. For example, a classroom may be used for a class of students, and then the *next* class comes in - a completely different set of students.

"Follow-up" normally refers to *continuing* situations where the *same* person or thing is involved in a sequence of events or appointments. For example, if a doctor sees a patient and determines that they need to come back for further treatment the next appointment may be called a "follow-up" appointment.

I think you may have mixed up "follow-up" with "the following", which can be used interchangeably with "next" in your context, although it sounds more natural when used with "class" than "students":

> I can't go for a break as I have to prepare the classroom for the following class.